# How to automatically load pretty-printers for gdb in CLion

Tags: gdb, clion

I have written some GDB pretty-printers for my user-defined c++ classes, and they work as expected.

My IDE is CLion, and the problem is I have to manually run 'source PrettyPrinters.py' from within gdb at the first debugging session.

How can I make CLion load these files automatically?

I understand there is a file called .gdbinit. I have tried to put my python script in this file. I have also tried to put 'source PrettyPrinters.py' in this file, but none of these attempts have been successful.

Note, I am using the bundled version of GDB, that comes with CLion.

Answer (score 1):

To answer my own question:

1. Add a '.gdbinit'-file to the root directory of the clion project.
2. Place the python script containing the pretty-printers definition in an appropriate directory. (I used this path and filename: 'project-root/gdb-pretty-printers/PrettyPrinters.py')
3. Add the command 'source project-root/gdb-pretty-printers/PrettyPrinters.py' to the .gdbinit file mentioned in (1).

Open the file '~/.config/gdb/gdbinit', or create it, if it does not already exist. Add the command 'add-auto-load-safe-path project-root/.gdbinit' to this file.

GDB should now load the pretty-printers automatically upon next debugging session (you do not need to restart clion).

Comment: In my alpine based docker image, '~/.config/gdb/gdbinit' was actually '/.config/gdb/gdbinit'.

Comment: `set auto-load local-gdbinit on` [might also be needed](https://www.jetbrains.com/help/clion/configuring-debugger-options.html#gdbinit-lldbinit)